# JSONLayout has no parameter that matches element KeyValuePair

Tags: log4j2

Below is the JSONLayout configure in log4j2.xml

```
        <JSONLayout complete="true" charset="UTF-8" compact="true">
            <KeyValuePair key="application-name" value="sample-app"></KeyValuePair>
        </JSONLayout>
```

POM.xml

```
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.7:compile
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.7:compile
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9:compile
```

I see the message is being printed in JSON format but somehow keyvalue pair is not being recognized.

```
2019-06-01 21:11:23,305 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR layout JSONLayout has no parameter that matches element KeyValuePair
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Any idea why keyvaluepair is not recognized?

Answer (score 3):

log4j2 version 2.7 does not have this `KeyValuePair` feature as nested element of `JSONLayout`. Use version `2.11.2` or above. Also, below log4j dependencies are required -

```
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.11.2:compile
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.11.2:compile
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9:compile
```